# How to use wait_for in a two node cluster docker container deployment?

Tags: docker, ansible

I have a cluster with two machines. I have a playbook to run a docker container in each one:

```
---
- hosts: machines_in_the_cluster

  tasks:
  - name: Run app container
    docker:
      name: "name"
      image: whatever:1.0
      pull: always
      state: reloaded
      ports:
      - "8080:8080"
```

It starts a tomcat server in each machine. But I don't want to execute the task in the second machine until the first has finished starting tomcat.

How can I solve it? Is there any kind of health checking via http? Is there a solution using wait_for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it by adding a task to wait for the tomcat start up:

```
  - name: Wait for server startup
    local_action: wait_for host={{inventory_hostname}} port={{port}} timeout=50 delay=10
```

This will wait 10 seconds doing nothing and then will start polling to check if port is available. If timeout is reached, task will fail.

I have also added `serial: 1` in the playbook (as ydaetskcoR mentions), in order to run tasks sequentally

Comment: Tasks are executed in parallel on all machines at once by default in Ansible, keeping them in lockstep. So this would restart both tomcat instances at the same time and then wait for them both to come back up.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I have put `serial: 1`, too, in order tu run them sequentially.

Comment: That answer then doesn't answer your original question and instead answers "How do I wait for Tomcat to be back up after being restarted" which is very different from what you asked.

Comment: I said : "But I don't want to execute the task in the second machine until the first has finished starting tomcat." Sorry if I haven't expressed myself well.

Comment: Yes and `serial` alone will support that as it will do _all_ of the tasks in the playbook for that number of hosts before doing any tasks for the next group of hosts

Comment: `serial` will support the task execution but not the tomcat startup, I think.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106495/discussion-between-ydaetskcor-and-bigdestroyer).

Answer (score 1):

You can run an entire playbook in [serial mode](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_delegation.html#rolling-update-batch-size) to make sure that Ansible completes the entire playbook against a subset of hosts before moving on to another set.

You can do this simply by adding the `serial` parameter to the playbook like so:

```
---
- hosts: machines_in_the_cluster

  serial: 1

  tasks:
  - name: Run app container
    ...
```

You can specify either an absolute number of hosts to do at a time (the above example just does one at a time) or a percentage of the available hosts. Running this:

```
- hosts: machines_in_the_cluster

  serial: 50%

  tasks:
  - name: Run app container
    ...
```

When you have 5 hosts in the targeted group will run 3 times, targeting the first 2 hosts, the second 2 hosts and then finally the last host.